# self submitting forms web2py

Tags: forms, model-view-controller, controller, web2py

I want to submit a form from a controller.So i had this code in the controller.However i see the submit button in the view.How to make the form submit from the controller itself?

PS:my intention is to add a record in the database.

```html
db.databasename.field.readable=False    #have done this for all the fields
db.databasename.field.writable=False
db.databasename.field.default=somevalue
form=SQLFORM(db.databasename).process()
if form.accepted:
  session.flash='accepted'
return locals()
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. The view specifies the UI that the user sees in the browser. If this is a form, the form must be presented to the user in the browser, where the user will be able to fill out and submit the form. There is no sense in which one would submit a form "from the controller." The controller is Python code that is run on the server -- it handles processing of the form data once it has been sent from the browser to the server. Can you explain in more detail what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Anthony My controller has different views and  i collect some data from the user and i  store them in session variables( like some lists).Finally i want to insert them into the database.This has to be automated.So in the controller i have created a form and made all the fields non-readable and not writeable and gave them default values.But i get the submit button in the view(actually there is no view for this function since it is only used to insert a record in database).

Comment: @user1576772 if the form has auth.signature then what will happen?

Comment: @user1576772  I want to update some field in a record of database form controller.How do i do that?
eg:In the table 'students' in the database  there is field called gender which is either 'male' or 'female'.Later i add a new field called 'gender_description'.It should be 'girl' when gender is female and 'boy' if gender is male.I want to populate this new field for all the records.How do i achieve this?

Comment: @sairamkolla auth.signature will be automatically filled when using insert().

Comment: @sairamkolla You'll have to ask another question for that. If I answered your current question, please accept it.

Comment: It's not clear how you could have a submit button in a view that you claim does not exist. Anyway, there is no need for a form here, just do a database [insert](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#insert) using the session values.

Comment: @yes anthony that  would do.I have already implemented that.THanks!!

Answer (score 0):

So you're trying to add a record from the controller? Just do:

`db.table_name.insert(field1 = "value1", field2 = "value2", field3 = "value3", ...)`